# im having problem with join on multi table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, inner-join

working on group chat web app with laravel

i want to perform search for user on particular group with their name

so basically there are three table

**users** -> `id` , `timeline_id` , `email` , `pw`

**timelines** -> `id` , `fname` , `lname` , `p_no`

**page_user**(defines user on particular group/page)  -> `id` , `page_id` , `user_id`

**page** -> `id` , `timeline_id`, `pg_name`

when i perform search on one selected group , query giving search from whole user not from selected group

```
`$page_members= DB::table('timelines')`
     `->join('users', 'timelines.id', '=', 'users.timeline_id')`    
     `->where('timelines.fname','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')`        ``
     `->orWhere('timelines.lname','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')`
     `->orWhere('users.email','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')`
     `->orderby('users.id', 'DESC')`
     `->get();`
```

where i need to do change ; considering that `$page_id = 1`; $q is search value;

Comment: By selecting a group, means choosing a particular page_id ? did you forget to apply the constraint for the $page_id ?

Comment: No, page_id is primary key for page table and foreign in page_user

Comment: can you show some data samples, and expected result

Comment: thankyou @Rashi , i solved that

Comment: great. please answer yourself below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$page_members= DB::table('timelines')
      ->join('users', 'timelines.id', '=', 'users.timeline_id')
      ->join('page_user', 'page_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
      ->select('users.*','timelines.*', 'timelines.name', 'timelines.lastname','timelines.username')
       ->where('timelines.name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
       ->where('page_user.page_id','=',$pgid)
       ->orWhere('timelines.lastname','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
       ->where('page_user.page_id','=',$pgid)
       ->orWhere('users.primarycontactno','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
       ->where('page_user.page_id','=',$pgid)
       ->orderby('users.id', 'DESC')
       ->get();
```

it worked but dont know why `->where('page_user.page_id','=',$pgid)` required more time , is that I did something wrong? if i put this on first place only then wont work for `timeline.lastname` and `users.primarycontactno` , if anyone has optimized solution do share;)